# Función InsertarAntesDe() en Lista Doble Circular en Golang

Tags: lista, insert, go

estoy implementando una lista doble circular en Golang y tengo el siguiente problema, pude armar correctamente la función de InsertarDespuesDe() para añadir valores a la lista y contiene la  siguiente estructura:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Nodo struct {
  Valor int
  Next *Nodo
  Prev *Nodo
}


func CrearLista(n int) *Nodo {
nn := &Nodo{
 Valor: n,
 Next: nil,
 Prev: nil,
}
nn.Next = nn
nn.Prev = nn

return nn
}


func InsertarDespuesDe(p *Nodo, valor int) *Nodo {  
nn := &Nodo{Valor: valor} 
q := p.Next
p.Next = nn
nn.Next = q
q.Prev = nn
nn.Prev = p

return nn
}



func main() {
 p := CrearLista(3)
n1 := InsertarDespuesDe(p, 7)
n2 := InsertarDespuesDe(n1, 11)
n3 := InsertarAntesDe(n1, 5) Esto de funcionar debería insertar el valor 5 antes del valor 7
 }
```

Luego de esto inserto 3 valores en la lista utilizando esta función (valores 3, 7 y 11) pero necesitaría crear una función (denominada InsertarAntesDe()) respetando la estructura de la función anterior y que cumpla la función inversa a esta e inserte un valor antes, pude llegar a crear una parte pero no funciona (se encuentra debajo), en que estoy fallando o me falta para completar la misma? Muchas Gracias.

```
func InsertarAntesDe(p *Nodo, valor int) *Nodo { 


nn := &Nodo{Valor: valor} 
q := p.Prev
p.Prev = nn
nn.Prev = q
q.Next = nn
nn.Next = p

return nn
}
```